# Python 3-x: Nested list in a for loop - how to get a "horizontal" output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for i, j in cards: 
# cards = a list containing list of cards - RANDOM OUTPUTS, more pairs can be added to the list depending on the number that the user puts in
        print(i)
        print(j)
        print("\t")
```

How do I make it so that the output becomes:

```
TS  6S  JS
AH  5S  AS
```

Instead of:

```
TS
AH

6S
5S

JS
AS
```

I posted a question similar to this but I wasn't being specific enough, and I edited too late. Apologies in advance

EDIT - 'cards' code:

```
deck = deck_create()
def deal_cards(deck, num_players):

    cards= []
    for i in range(num_players):

        hands.append([deck.pop(), deck.pop()])

    return hands
```

Comment: What is an example of what `cards` looks like when it's input to the loop?

Comment: post some sample input for cards

Comment: I have added the code for 'cards'. deck_create() is another function I've made which creates a deck of 52 shuffled cards.

Comment: okay, I added a solution, please check @DwightD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need,

```
for i in range(len(cards[0])):
    for items in cards:
        if items[i] in cards[-1]:
            print(items[i],end="\n")
        else:
             print(items[i],end="\t")
```

Answer (score 4):

You could get a little fancy and use `zip(*)` to transpose `cards`. Then printing is simple, like this:

```
cards=[("TS", "AH"), ("6S", "5S"), ("JS", "AS")]
for round in zip(*cards):
    print('\t'.join(round))
```

output:

```
TS  6S  JS
AH  5S  AS
```

Comment: I think this is the most pythonic way (would not say its fancy at all)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, run the loop twice. Character output only allows you  to operate on one line at a time, reliably.  To print in vertical columns requires stripping the data in two passes.  Using an IF statement, inside a loop slows down processing compared to just running it twice. Python can optimize this kind of code, because it doesn't need branch prediction.

```
cards=[ ("TS","AH"), ("6S","5S"),("JS","AS") ] #This is dummy data, to match your code. Replace it.
for i,j in cards: 
    print (i,"\t", end="")
print()
for i,j in cards:
    print (j,"\t", end="")
print()
```